# MySQL - Relatório de carros mais vendidos usando View

Tags: mysql

Uma ideia de como posso criar uma *View* realizando a **criação de um relatório em ordem decrescentes com os carros mais alugados em um certo período de tempo**.  Exibindo neste relatório, a placa do veículo, o total da quilometragem rodada durante o período de tempo informado, a quantidade de locações realizadas durante o período de tempo e a quilometragem atual do veículo??

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Estrutura das acima tabelas:**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_carros (
  ID_CARROS int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PLACA varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  MODELO varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  ANO varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  COR varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  QUILOM varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  SITUACAO varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  DESCRICAO varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  TBL_CLASSES_DO_CARRO_ID_CLASSES int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID_CARROS,TBL_CLASSES_DO_CARRO_ID_CLASSES),
  KEY fk_TBL_CARROS_TBL_CLASSES_DO_CARRO1_idx (TBL_CLASSES_DO_CARRO_ID_CLASSES),
  CONSTRAINT fk_TBL_CARROS_TBL_CLASSES_DO_CARRO1 FOREIGN KEY (TBL_CLASSES_DO_CARRO_ID_CLASSES) REFERENCES tbl_classes_do_carro (ID_CLASSES) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE tbl_reservas (
  MULTA int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  VALOR_TOTAL int(11) NOT NULL,
  SITUACAO varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  DATA_RETORNO date NOT NULL,
  DATA_LOCACAO date NOT NULL,
  QUILOM_RODADOS int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  QUANT_DIARIA varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  TBL_CLIENTES_ID_CLIENTES int(11) NOT NULL,
  TBL_FILIAIS_ID_FILIAIS int(11) NOT NULL,
  TBL_CARROS_ID_CARROS int(11) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (TBL_CLIENTES_ID_CLIENTES,TBL_FILIAIS_ID_FILIAIS,TBL_CARROS_ID_CARROS),
  KEY fk_TBL_RESERVAS_TBL_CLIENTES_idx (TBL_CLIENTES_ID_CLIENTES),
  KEY fk_TBL_RESERVAS_TBL_FILIAIS1_idx (TBL_FILIAIS_ID_FILIAIS),
  KEY fk_TBL_RESERVAS_TBL_CARROS1_idx (TBL_CARROS_ID_CARROS),
  CONSTRAINT fk_TBL_RESERVAS_TBL_CARROS1 FOREIGN KEY (TBL_CARROS_ID_CARROS) REFERENCES tbl_carros (ID_CARROS) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_TBL_RESERVAS_TBL_CLIENTES FOREIGN KEY (TBL_CLIENTES_ID_CLIENTES) REFERENCES tbl_clientes (ID_CLIENTES) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_TBL_RESERVAS_TBL_FILIAIS1 FOREIGN KEY (TBL_FILIAIS_ID_FILIAIS) REFERENCES tbl_filiais (ID_FILIAIS) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Pode complementar com mais informações? Nome da tabela A, nome da tabela B. Qual a FK da tabela B com a tabela A. Se puder colocar o script de criação, acho que ajudaria a formular uma resposta. Obrigado

Comment: Ok, Hiago. A estrutura das tabelas acima são:

Comment: Pacato, acho melhor apagar a resposta, e editar sua pergunta.

Comment: Certo,obrigada pela dica

Answer (score -1):

Segue abaixo o `select` que você pode usar para gerar sua View.

> Observação: Lembre-se de alterar os valores de :menorData e :maiorData para o intervalo que você deseja.

```
SELECT 
    c.PLACA as Placa, SUM(r.QUILOM_RODADOS) as KMRodados,
    COUNT(1) as QTDLocacoesPeriodo, ANY_VALUE(c.QUILOM) as KMAtual
FROM
tbl_carros c
INNER JOIN tbl_reservas r ON r.TBL_CARROS_ID_CARROS = c.ID_CARROS
WHERE 
r.DATA_LOCACAO between ':menorData' and ':maiorData'
GROUP BY Placa
ORDER BY KMRodados DESC;
```

Comment: É exatamente esse select Hiago, obrigado !!